# ajax call is not working while pulling api call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to get blog details of your website through ajax call but I am getting

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

```
$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback:'callback',
  contentType:"application/json",
  url:"https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts/"+5067937629+"?hapikey=**********"
  success: function (data) {} });
```

Comment: Please frame the question properly. Separating the code you have written and the error you are getting. Try formatting code snippets in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! well you just have a comma(,) missing after the url parameter. Try fixing that and run again.

```
  url:"https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts/"+5067937629+"?hapikey=**********",
```

This can cause a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" exception

Comment: $.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     dataType: "jsonp",
     jsonpCallback:'callback',
      url:"https://api.hubapi.com/content/api/v2/blog-posts/5067937629?hapikey=********",
      headers: {
                   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
               },
       success: function (data) {
     console.log(data.topic_ids[0]); }});    This is what I did but still I am getting the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: No. It shouldn't. Then probably you have some issue around the js surrounding this too. To check if this piece of code will work, just copy n paste it in the browser debugger. Then run it.

Comment: yes, I did the same, but the Issue is with Hubspot it does not allow any client-side API calls.